# c# How to add unbound check box column to WinForms with DevExpress(Gridview)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview, checkbox, devexpress

I want to add check box column to gridview without choosing Data source because I'm using a dataAdapter. I've searched google, but I think there is no case like me. Please help me to examples or solution...
(I use Visual studio 2013 c#, DevExpress(gridcontrol), Mssql)

Comment: Have you searched "add checkbox column to gridview dynamically winform"?

Comment: can you link the site for me? I'll check..

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-CheckBox-Column-to-DataGridView-in-Windows-Forms-application-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you've tried to add this checkbox column to emulate check-selection. From version 13.2, the GridView in the XtraGrid control provides a built-in checkbox column for multiple row selection. 
To enable this feature, set the properties as follows.

- Set [ColumnViewOptionsSelection.MultiSelect](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnViewOptionsSelection_MultiSelecttopic.aspx) to **true**.
- Set [GridOptionsSelection.MultiSelectMode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsSelection_MultiSelectModetopic) to [GridMultiSelectMode.CheckBoxRowSelect](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridMultiSelectModeEnumtopic.aspx).

Take a look at the [Multiple Row Selection via Built-In Check Column](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument16439) help-article for details.

Online Video: [DevExpress WinForms: Web Style Row Selection.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKNH7cLnKMA)